# custom css for admin only

Tags: php, css

I need custom CSS for admin. So if user is not logged in or is anything else but admin there is one CSS, and for admin only different CSS.

I tried this code in functions.php:

```
function wpa66834_role_admin_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $current_user;
    foreach( $current_user->roles as $role )
        $classes .= ' role-' . $role;
    return trim( $classes );
}
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'wpa66834_role_admin_body_class' );
```

and in custom CSS field:

```
#targetElement { 
    display: none; 
}
.role-administrator #targetElement { 
    display: visible; 
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want it to affect the frontend of the site or the admin area/backend?

Comment: On fronted. Pages that are visible to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you've tried already adds the role CSS class to the `admin_body_class`, which only affects the admin area/backend. Simply change the filter to alter the frontend body class `body_class`, eg.

```
function wpa66834_role_admin_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $current_user;
    foreach( $current_user->roles as $role )
        $classes .= ' role-' . $role;
    return trim( $classes );
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpa66834_role_admin_body_class' );
```

Comment: Also, referencing the original question "display: visible" is not correct CSS, and, referencing the PHP code, should probably use sanitize_html_class(), not trim().

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
function add_custom_styles() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {  ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .site-description {
            display: none !important;
        }
        .site-title {
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>
<?php }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_styles');
```

Comment: Although this code will work, it will not utilise the themes built-in custom CSS field as the OP described in their question. A small change to their code is all that is required and this will make it so that any custom CSS changes will only need to be done in one place, rather than two...

Comment: Just realised that it was you who asked the question. Please see my answer above as this will be easier for you to maintain the CSS code going forward...